# C++ run executable and pipe output to file

Tags: c++, mfc

To start off with, I'm pretty new to C++.

I am wanting to accomplish the following:

- Execute the following: "SampleApp.exe -cf test.xml"
- I need the shell that execute in hidden mode
- I need the C++ application to wait until SampleApp is finished
- If the SampleApp takes longer than X amount of time, then I need to terminate the process
- I want to pipe SampleApp's output to a file (sample.log)

So far I have the following:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO lpExecInfo;
lpExecInfo.cbSize  = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
lpExecInfo.lpFile = L"SampleApp.exe";
lpExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_DOENVSUBST|SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;     
lpExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;  
lpExecInfo.lpVerb = L"open";
lpExecInfo.lpParameters = L"-cf test.xml";
lpExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
lpExecInfo.nShow = SW_HIDE; // hide shell during execution
lpExecInfo.hInstApp = (HINSTANCE) SE_ERR_DDEFAIL;
ShellExecuteEx(&lpExecInfo);

// wait until the process is finished
if (lpExecInfo.hProcess != NULL)
{
    ::WaitForSingleObject(lpExecInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    ::CloseHandle(lpExecInfo.hProcess);
}
```

The above code achieves everything except piping output to a file.
However, I doesn't seem to be possible with ShellExecute.
It seems that I need to use CreateProcess instead.
I am hoping that someone with more C++ experience would be able to provide me with the CreateProcess equivalent of my code plus piping output. If not, at least confirm that what I am wanting to do is possible and point me in the right direction.

- Thanks

Comment: There a multiple examples on the Internet (including this site), that shows how to use `CreateProcess` to create child-processes where the parent captures the output from the child.

Comment: Yes, I know but it seems that CreateProcess is quite a bit more complex than ShellExecute and the examples that I have found have varying degrees of complexity as well. I was hoping to get some advice on where to look based on my needs or even some good example code that accomplishes what I need or some of what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you're feeling particularly masochistic or truly need to optimize this operation, use `_popen` to create the child process. That will return a `FILE *` from which you can read the child's output. Read from there, write to file, done.

```
FILE *child = _popen("child.exe", "r");
FILE *result = fopen("result.txt", "w");

// error checking omitted.

char buffer[1024];

while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), child))
    fputs(buffer, result);
```

Doing this on your own (using the Windows API) is certainly possible and can even reduce overhead, but it's *tremendously* more work.

Answer (score 1):

Your going to want to familiarize yourself with [this code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), as it's exactly what you want to do. 
You will need to add some code to [write to file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in the `ReadFromPipe` function.